# Changing a color depending on iPhone colour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, colors

I've been working a lot on my new project's colour scheme and concluded that one scheme is the best for use on the white iPhone while a different set should be used on the black one.
How can I specify different picture files to be used on the device depending on its colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can get access to the SN of the phone along with the apple database dicating the color of each phone this won't be possible.

I would recommend instead giving the user an option so that they can pick to change the color scheme of your app.

Comment: The model number is enough to determine the color, and you can match that to [this list](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Models). However, I don't believe there is a way to determine the exact model number, either.